# Pass strings with comma from Automation Anywhere to Excel Macro

Tags: macros, automationanywhere

I am trying to run a Macro from Automation Anywhere. I am trying to pass a string as parameter of Macro.

The problem is String has comma(,) in it and Automation Anywhere uses Comma(,) for separating parameters

Example data:

> Example, Example Media. ltd.

This is just 1 parameter but Automation Anywhere treats it as two different parameters

I Tried:

1. Enclosing Parameter in Single Quote and Double Quote - **Doesn't Work**

I have 2 Workarounds:

**Workaround 1**

Setting Data in Cell and then Macro will read it - **Working Fine**

**Workaround 2**

Replacing Comma(,) with Tilde(~) and then Macro will replace back - **Working Fine**

Even if I have a working solution(I made solution work by alternate ways as explained above) I was wondering is there any way in Automation Anywhere for doing this in proper parameter way

Comment: **Workaround 3:** Try to pass it as a variable.

Comment: @KhaledMostafaMe We are selecting data from a database and passing it to macro. Basically through variable already :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. the workarounds are great, I will try to implement the second.
Automation Anywhere treats it as two different parameters even if it's passed as variable. using the action run macros using params is not very common but very useful, thanks for supporting workarounds strategies

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already have some working options. So anything else is optional. Something I've seen success you could try with your case:

- Make a `list` in Automation Anywhere with each of your macros.
- Use the `String Operation -> Join` using a comma as the delimiter.
- Assign that join to a variable
- Insert that variable into your Run Excel Macro command

Often the commas, or whatever other special characters in Automation Anywhere, only provide special properties at "compile-time" (when you save) and not "run-time".

I've not tested this method on your scenario, but just a nice trick to try and leverage that keeps your code in AA rather than having a floating dependency in Excel land.

Comment: We are already passing individual parameters through AA variables already. are you telling me to put all the parameters in one single variable as pass it to Macro?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented **Workaround 2**, I will share the simple example as someone can use it further if needed:

On Automation Anywhere i used string Replace Action to change every comma for "~"

for examplification, my **$macroParam$** variable is something like that:

BEFORE: "**{arn_, ART },{cin_, TEST },**"

AFTER: "**{arn_~ ART }~{cin_~ TEST }~**"

[image]

In the macro code you will need to add a step to revert the process, so you can keep all the rest of the code exactly the same (this way you don't additionally need to change entire logic from "," to "~" in the macro )

```
Sub Main(param As String)
   'Before performing manipulations, revert ~ to , 
   param = Replace(param, "~", ",")

   ....rest of the code can keep the same
End Sub
```